# Current drive capability

Tags: gpio

Can someone point out the mistake I'm making in reading this graph (which is from the ADI Blackfin 70x datasheet)

If a driver was set high, to 1.8V, why would it be unable to source current? I'm reading up from 1.8V on the X-axis and going up to the middle Voh line, then over to the Y-axis.

[image]

Comment: which of the lines do you read and what is the reading you get? I arrive at more or less 0mA

Comment: because the power supply is 1.8V on that line. It is supplied by 1.8V and producing 1.8V - voltage difference = 0 - hence 0 current

Comment: so then i should think of this as "steady state"? If I'm visualizing the driver switching from high to low do I just ride the line back down to 0, with it source current increasing to a max of ~22mA until it reaches Vol, at which point I drop down to the Vol line where we're back to 0mA?

Comment: The reason this graph was so confusing to me is that the cause is the current (determined by the load) and the effect is the voltage being pulled down. This would have been clearer if the axes were swapped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any amplifier - including this driver - has some output resistance. If you draw current from it, some voltage is dropped across this output resistance.

So the only way to see the open-circuit output voltage is with - well, an open circuit, i.e. to draw no current.

If you draw some current - say, 5 mA, the output voltage reduces by 0.4V.
So the output resistance - or more properly, source impedance, is 0.4/0.005 = 80 ohms. (Approximately; as the load line isn't straight, the source impedance varies a little according to the load current).

Knowing this allows you to design the PCB to get good pulse shapes - you can design the PCB traces and any termination for a characteristic impedance that matches the driver.

Comment: Of course, now it makes perfect sense. I should think of it as "here's what the actual output voltage will be if you slap on a constant current load of this value".

Comment: by the way, in this case if you wen't with the "usual" 50 ohm trace you'd be way off, correct?

Comment: Right but a 50 ohm trace tends to be quite wide, 80 ohms looks like a good choice. I'm guessing it's deliberate, but AD probably have application notes or design guidelines with more info.